# How to rename a selected text from a file?

Tags: c#, listbox, rename

I've made a program where you can add text over textbox and it adds it into a listbox. Now to actually save it on the next time when the application launches, I decided to store it into some text.ini file.

Now that the next time the application launches (form load), using the StreamReader it reads all the text from that file and displays it into a listbox.

I have decided to implement an edit functionality (select the item from listbox -> right click -> edit), and rename the file (in case something was misspelled).

My problem is this:

If I have 1 item in the listbox and rename it, it works perfectly fine.

But if I have 2 or more items in the listbox but decide to rename only 1, it removes all text from the file and renames only the selected item.

This is my code:

```
string itemName = (string)lBoxRadioLinks.SelectedItem;
var renameFile = Interaction.InputBox("Enter a new name for the file:", "Rename File", itemName);

// Gets the selected item full name
var url = lBoxRadioLinks.GetItemText(lBoxRadioLinks.SelectedIndex);
string lineToRename = url.ToString();

// Selected file
//MessageBox.Show(lineToRename);

// ACTUALLY rename the text
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("IO/sites.ini");
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line != lineToRename)
        list.Add(line);
}

// Have to convert the string into array for an actual rename
string[] arr = new string[] { renameFile };

// Visually rename the file (display in listbox asap)
lBoxRadioLinks.DataSource = arr;

// Renames the file
File.WriteAllLines("IO/sites.ini", arr);
```

Obviously the method "WriteAllLines" will rename the whole text inside of a file, but I don't want that.

How can I rename a text that is at a certain line, without effecting other lines in a file?

Comment: Are you talking about renaming files, or replacing text *in* files?

Comment: Replacing text inside the file.
For example, I have this inside of a file:

Hello
World

Let's say I selected the 2nd item and want to rename it into "Text", so inside of the file it should be

Hello
Text

Comment: Where is `renameFile` even defined?

Comment: Sorry about that, check the code again.

Comment: It sure sounds like you're trying to rename a file, not replace the text in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you're asking, but I'll give this my best shot.

If we're understanding each other when we agree that you want to *replace certain text in a text file*, and if you're actually okay loading the whole thing into memory, then you might as well just use the `string.Replace` method.

```
Dictionary<string, string> changesToMake = ...;
var contents = File.ReadAllText(filename);

foreach(var change in changesToMake)
{
    contents = contents.Replace(change.Key, change.Value);
}

File.WriteAllText(filename, contents);
```

As for the problem you're having with multiple items in the `ListBox`, you're only referencing the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` properties, so nothing should get changed anywhere other than at those...files? I'm still not even sure of what's in that `ListBox`. If you want to alter more than one at a time, you should be using the pluralized forms of each of those properties to access all of the selected items and not just the first.

Comment: It worked! Your first idea:

var contents = File.ReadAllText("IO/sites.ini");
File.WriteAllText("IO/sites.ini", contents.Replace(lineToRename, renameFile));

It successfully renames a single line in a text file without effecting other text, which is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. Please mark this as an answer to help any people with a similar problem in the future.